# Moving a character with Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am new to Lua and am attempting to simulate a character moving. 
I have the character moving left and right at the moment. I would like the character to move 16 pixels at a time. That works fine given that the user doesn't touch the phone rapidly. In that case, the character moves a random number of pixels.

my question is, how can i get the touch event to only register once at a time.

**my code:**

```
-- move character
function moveCharacter(event)
    if  event.phase == 'began' then
        if event.x > character.x+8 then
            transition.to(background, {time=800, x=background.x-16})
        end

        if event.x < character.x-8 then
            transition.to(background, {time=800, x=background.x+16})
        end
    end
end

function touchScreen(event)
    Runtime:removeEventListener('touch', moveCharacter)

    if  event.phase == 'began' then
        Runtime:addEventListener('touch', moveCharacter)
    end

end

Runtime:addEventListener('touch', touchScreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function moveCharEF()
     if event.x > character.x+8 then
         background.x = background - 16
     end    
     if event.x < character.x-8 then
         background.x = background + 16
     end
end

function moveCharacter(event)
    if  event.phase == 'began' then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( event.target )
        event.target.isFocus = true
        Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", moveCharEF )
    elseif event.target.isFocus then
        if event.phase == "ended" then
            Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", moveCharEF )
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            event.target.isFocus = false
        end
    end
end

function touchScreen(event)
    Runtime:removeEventListener('touch', moveCharacter)

    if  event.phase == 'began' then
        Runtime:addEventListener('touch', moveCharacter)
    end

end

Runtime:addEventListener('touch', touchScreen)
```

By the way, I dont know about your application. So character may move too fast or too slow. Just change moveCharEF() function's related lines

Answer (score 0):

Is it is what you looking for..?

```
local isTransitionInProgress = false

local function resetFlag()
   isTransitionInProgress = false
end

function moveCharacter(event)
   if(event.x > character.x+8 and isTransitionInProgress==false)  then
     isTransitionInProgress = true
     transition.to(background, {time=800, x=background.x-16,onComplete=resetFlag()})
   end

   if(event.x < character.x-8 and isTransitionInProgress==false) then
     isTransitionInProgress = true
     transition.to(background, {time=800, x=background.x+16,onComplete=resetFlag()})
   end
end

background:addEventListener("tap", moveCharacter)
```

Keep coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the "tap" listener instead of "touch". It only registers one touch at a time.

```
Runtime:addEventListener('tap', touchScreen)
```